# Displaying a random image with matching title in React slideshow component on page load and button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a slideshow that displays a random image with its associated title when the page loads or when you click the next button from the slideshow. I'm doing this in a React component. I made an array of objects, each with the image URL and the title. I'm trying to write the function I would need to choose a random image and be able to display both the image and the title. Here's what I have so far. I'm not really sure where to begin. Thank you, I really appreciate it!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/slideshow.css";

export default class Slideshow extends Component {
  images = [
    {
      headline: "Title 1",
      link:
        "www.example1.com"
    },
    {
      headline: "Title 2",
      link:
        "www.example2.com"
    },
    {
      headline: "Title 3",
      link:
        "www.example3.com"
    }
  ];

  displayRandomImage = () => {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="slideshow" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block" src={} alt="First slide" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <a
            class="carousel-control-prev"
            href="#carouselExampleControls"
            role="button"
            data-slide="prev"
          >
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a
            class="carousel-control-next"
            href="#carouselExampleControls"
            role="button"
            data-slide="next"
          >
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/slideshow.css";

export default class Slideshow extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      imgIndex: null
    };
  }

  images = [
    {
      headline: "Title 1",
      link: "www.example1.com"
    },
    {
      headline: "Title 2",
      link: "www.example2.com"
    },
    {
      headline: "Title 3",
      link: "www.example3.com"
    }
  ];

  componentWillMount() {
    this.displayRandomImage();
  }

  displayRandomImage = () => {
    this.setState({
      imgIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="slideshow" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div className="carousel-inner">
            <div className="carousel-item active">
                <div className='carousel-image_title'>{this.images[imgIndex].headline}</div>
              <img
                className="d-block"
                src={this.images[imgIndex].link}
                alt="First slide"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <a
            className="carousel-control-prev"
            href="#carouselExampleControls"
            role="button"
            data-slide="prev"
          >
            <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a
            className="carousel-control-next"
            href="#carouselExampleControls"
            role="button"
            data-slide="next"
          >
            <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

    enter code here
```